openssl dynamic linking from Cross.toml needs at runtime libssl1.0.0 which doesn't exist anymore
In my project I need to use openssl not for the HTTP part of my app but because I need to decode signed file.
I added to my Cargo.toml:
openssl = { version = "0.10.66", default-features = false }

and to Cross.toml:
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
pre-build = [
    "dpkg --add-architecture $CROSS_DEB_ARCH",
    "apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes libssl-dev:$CROSS_DEB_ARCH",
]

When I launch cross it builds but when the --release executable runs on Debian 12 machine with openssl installed the error is:
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Why is it bound to libssl.so.1.0.0 and not to latest versions?
The openssl installed on the machine is:
openssl version -a

OpenSSL 3.0.14 4 Jun 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.14 4 Jun 2024)
built on: Sun Sep  1 14:59:10 2024 UTC
platform: debian-arm64
options:  bn(64,64)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -fzero-call-used-regs=used-gpr -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=2 -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/reproducible-path/openssl-3.0.14=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/engines-3"
MODULESDIR: "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ossl-modules"
Seeding source: os-specific
CPUINFO: OPENSSL_armcap=0xbd

If I use ldd I get this:
ldd executable
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffb51f0000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffffb3fe0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000ffffb3fb0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffffb3f10000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000ffffb3ee0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffb3d30000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffb51b3000)


You probably have different versions of the libssl-dev and libssl packages. Note: if you run readelf -d /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so on the building environment, the SONAME field will give you the file name that programs built with this version of libssl-dev expect.

Our problem here is, that the docker image that cross uses for our "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"-target is out of date - the maintainers said they'll update it soon - see https://github.com/cross-rs/cross/issues/1567
In the mean time we could try to use a custom image, but sadly my attempts to do so failed so far..
